# Create fixed sidebar and fixed menu bar with css/html with "browser chosen width/height"

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to create a fixed sidebar and fixed menu bar and a content page like this example with bootstrap:

[image]

For the menu bar, I use the following css (which works)

```
.fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

But what css shall I use for the sidebar? Because I do not know the height of the menubar (and I do not want set it explicitly, but let the browser choose). How to attach the sidebar to the bottom of the menu bar?

```
.fixed-left {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  .... (how to set it fixed to the bottom of the menubar?)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: try adding `top: 0` and  `bottom: 0` to `.fixed-left`

Answer (score 0):

Modify some css in `.fixed-left`

```
.fixed-left {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; // set it equal as the height of fixed-top 
  bottom: 0; // so that it will stick to bottom
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow-y: auto; // it will have the scroll if it has more content
  width: 250px; // set as per your requirement
}
```

Comment: Thanks - but then the "Search Box" in the example above would move below the menubar. How to avoid that?

Comment: @Defarine you can add `margin-top` to `search-box` or you can give `padding-top` to `fixed-left`. the solution may vary as per your markup and your requirement.